# Which graphics / video card to choose?

Tags: graphics-card

I am in Bangladesh. I am looking for an entry level graphics card (within $ 100-120) for my new i5-4570 processor + Gigabyte Z87-HD3 motherboard system. I am not a gamer and also understand next to nothing about graphics cards, or for that matter much about hardware.

Can you tell me which is the best and most suitable for my processor+motherboard combination among the following choices :--

1. Sapphire R7 250 1GB DDR5
2. Gigabyte GT640 DDR3
3. Gigabyte GV-N640 2GB DDR5 (Memory Bus: 64 bit)
4. Gigabyte GV- R7770C 1GB DDR5
5. Sapphire R7 250X 1GB DDR5
6. Gigabyte R7 250X 1GB DDR5

For detailed specs of the these cards, you can check the following links :-
(a) http://www.ryanscomputers.com/Graphics-Card/All-Brands/10 (for the first four in the list), and
(b) http://www.ryanscomputers.com/Graphics-Card/All-Brands/20 (for the last two in the list)

These links are from a local Bangladeshi vendor's website. These are the only ones I can find within my budget and desired entry-level (?) specs - from a local seller.

I was thinking of buying a GDDR5+2GB-memory graphics card in less than BDT 9,000 (ie $100-120). Only one of these cards (listed above) has that within my budget - Gigabyte GV-N640 2GB DDR5 (Nvidia Geforce GT 640). But its memory bus (Memory Interface Width?) is 64-bit, half of all other G-cards appxly within this price range. Does this make any significant difference?  What is the impact of bits of bus on Gcards and what is the effect of being 64-bit memory bus (Memory Interface Width?) instead of 128 bit? Is it better to get a 1GB DDR5 card with 128-bit memory bus, instead of a 2GB DDR5 card with 64-bit
memory bus?  Also,  - which feature /spec in a GCard is most important for faster and better performance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Memory bus can be 64-bit or 128-bit No big difference in performance... The real best performance rely upon "GPU Clock speed" and "Memory Clock speed"..
Choose this(from the first link in your question):
 **Gigabyte GV-N640 2GB DDR5**
**Product ID: 14.018.103**
ONLY this card has the top Clock speed of both memory & GPU.. and supports OpenGL 4.2..(that's great) and also fits in your budget(BDT 8600)..

This card's(64-bit) clock speed is much higher than 128-bit card(BDT 9300)so no worry..and for 128-bit graphics card, power consumption will be higher.

2 GB is better than 1 GB.. Processing speed(clock speed) of GPU determines the speed & performance of Graphics cards.

Comment: eh, lower the bus width, slower are the data transfers. Classic games not utilizing 128-bit graphics card is wrong. 2GB better than 1Gb is again wrong.